# Trying to edit a file inside a docker but it returns to default file with no changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker

I was getting an error as the following

> Blocked host: xx.xxx.xxx To allow requests to xx.xxx.xxx, add the following to your environment configuration: config.hosts << "xx.xxx.xxx"

and as mentioned in a lot of posts I've to edit `config/environments/development.rb` file from inside the docker to add the following line `config.hosts << "xx.xxx.xxx"` but when I edit the file with vim and I restart the server the default file returns with no changes.

Comment: can you provide some more information about the docker image you are using? specifically, what is the entrypoint and command?

Comment: You'll probably want some more durable way of changing this configuration, either by bind-mounting an alternate configuration into the container or by changing the image's source.  If you live-edit files inside containers those changes will be lost as soon as the container is deleted (and deleting containers is very routine).

Answer (score 0):

You can always manage the files outside of Docker.

Let's say your container name is: **uitest**

Make a folder for it on your computer.

```
mkdir -p ~/docker/uitest
cd ~/docker/uitest
```

Then copy the files that you need to modify there.

```
docker cp uitest:/config/environments/development.rb .
docker cp uitest:/etc/hosts .
```

Make the wanted file changes on your local machine.

Then you can either copy the files back in the container.

```
docker cp development.rb uitest:/config/environments/development.rb
docker cp hosts uitest:/etc/hosts
```

or if practical remove the old container

```
docker rm uitest
```

and recreate it with the volumes

```
docker run -dit --name uitest \
-v $PWD/development.rb:/config/environment/development.rb \
-v $PWD/hosts:/etc/hosts \
uitest/image
```